# How can I hide a div with if else render react?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to hide an Event div when there is no event date showing

Here is how my project look like:

[image]

and here is how it appear when there is no event on that day:

[image]

Here is my following component code:

```
  <div className="event-list-item-content">
              <div className="header">
                <span className="announcements">Events</span>
                <button className="plus">
                  <ControlPoint />
                </button>
              </div>
              {teamData.Events.map((event, index) => (
                <div key={index} className="list-events-description">
                  {moment(event.date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") ===
                    moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD") && (
                    <div className="content">
                      {event.description}
                      <span>
                        {moment(event.timestart, "HH:mm:ss").format("h:mm A")}
                        <svg
                          width="8"
                          height="12"
                          viewBox="0 0 8 12"
                          fill="none"
                          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                        >
                          <path
                            d="M0.589844 1.41L5.16984 6L0.589843 10.59L1.99984 12L7.99984 6L1.99984 6.16331e-08L0.589844 1.41Z"
                            fill="#00A682"
                          />
                        </svg>
                      </span>
                      <hr />
                    </div>
                  )}
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
```

How can I hide this element ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether teamData.Events is empty. If it is not, then display. Otherwise, it will not be shown.

```
<div className='event-list-item-content'>
    {teamData.Events.length !== 0 && (
    <div className='header'>
        <span className='announcements'>Events</span>
        <button className='plus'>
        <ControlPoint />
        </button>
    </div>
    )}
    {teamData.Events.map((event, index) => (
    <div key={index} className='list-events-description'>
        {moment(event.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') === moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD') && (
        <div className='content'>
            {event.description}
            <span>
            {moment(event.timestart, 'HH:mm:ss').format('h:mm A')}
            <svg width='8' height='12' viewBox='0 0 8 12' fill='none' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
                <path d='M0.589844 1.41L5.16984 6L0.589843 10.59L1.99984 12L7.99984 6L1.99984 6.16331e-08L0.589844 1.41Z' fill='#00A682' />
            </svg>
            </span>
            <hr />
        </div>
        )}
    </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: teamData.Events always have when I render the component

Comment: change it to `teamData.Events.length !== 0 && <div>...</div>`

Comment: When I render the page it already have the `teamData.Events` because i store it in database so whenever I click to this component it will send me the teamData.Events, so is there any way we can implement this ?

Comment: You may want to set teamData.Events into React state when fetch from database using ```setState()``` and check whether the state is empty or not ```this.state.yourVariable```. React will re-render if there's any changes to the state.